# Hibernate cannot auto create a table in database1 if there exists another table with the same name in another database2

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

It is wried that I have two databases. One db's name is db1 and another one is db2. When I switch my database to db and let hiberate create tables for me (use Entity Annotation), It just won't create new tables for me in db1, since there already exists name table name in db2.

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SchemaExtractionException: More than one table found in namespace (, ) : schemaConfig

Comment: Pls provide more details with error msg and code being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Hibernate version is too low. I used 
`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And I switched to 5.2.9 and the problem disappeared.
Don't know why